# "Error: Could not find or load main class ..."

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class bookreader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //...
    }
}
```

When I run this code normally it spits out:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bookreader
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)

When I debug the code it spits out:

> Error: Could not find or load main class bookreader

I'm pretty sure both errors are the same, but I don't know how to fix either of them. Other answer point towards it running as a wrong file type, but the name of the file is `bookreader.java` which should run it in Java like needed in Intellij.

Comment: No package statements? Has it managed to compile correctly?

Comment: Check if all required jar's are added to classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Try the down-to-up method: Code a simple "Hello world" class, with no packages and no imports, and run it from the IDE. If it compiles well but does not run, either the project is not OK, or either the IDE is not OK.

Instead, if it runs, add more logic to this dummy class to make it resemble your initial class, repeating the test after every edit. When it fails, you'll know what was the last edit.

Comment: My code does not even compile. I get this error: "Error:java: /production/MyProjectName: does not exist". I do not know what this production directory is or where it's supposed to go. I've tried making it myself and adding it in all sorts of different directories in my project, but it always gives the same error. I've tried opening the run configurations and setting the fields there; I made sure the main class was chosen properly, and I made sure the project directory was chosen correctly and nothing changes. halp!

Comment: @OKGimmeMoney Open a new issue and explain your experiment in detail, please.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling the class/Running the program like this :

"**java bookreader**" and NOT like "**java bookreader.class**"